# In which case does Google Cloud Pub/Sub close a subscription?

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Google Cloud Pub/Sub: Node.js Client 2.19.0.

It happens from time to time that messages on some subscriptions simply do not get acked. My suspicion is that something with the subscription goes wrong sometimes.
I have a `subscription.on('error', ...` listener. However, this listener is obviously not triggered when the problem occurs.

Could it be that the subscription is closed without an error being thrown?

I could not find any background information in the [official docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/pubsub/latest/Subscription.html) but they entail the following about event handlers:

```
// Register a close handler in case the subscriber closes unexpectedly
subscription.on('close', () => {});
```

That raises the question: In which cases is subscription closed unexpectedly?

Does it make sense to add a listener for re-opening like

```
subscription.on('close', () => {
    subscription.open()
});
```

?

If so: What would be the preferred way to distinguish between unexpected closing (to which I want to react by re-opening) and my own program-code having closed a subscription on purpose (in which case I do not want to re-open the subscription automatically)?

Comment: Hi @cis, can you please tell how are you handling the on error? Are you restarting the subscription.on("message", messageHandler); message listener on some particular error, if so please mention them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subscriber should not be closed without an error being thrown. There are several reasons why a subscriber may be closed including:

- The subscription was deleted.
- The subscriber no longer has permission to subscribe to the subscription.
- There was an unexpected bug in the client library itself that caused a close.

One question would be, what do you mean by messages are not getting acked? Is it that you are getting the messages again after you believe you have called `ack` on them? Is it that the number of unacked messages you see in Cloud Monitoring is not decreasing?

If your messages are not getting acked, there could be many different causes. It could be that your message processing failed and didn't ack the message. This would not cause the entire subscriber to error out, but would only result in an eventual `nack` for the message that wasn't processed. It can be helpful to log every message you receive at the very beginning of your callback and log every ack to ensure that you are acking every message.

You could also be running into the note about acks for batched messages in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#dupes):

> When the Pub/Sub client libraries batch multiple messages into a single call to the service, all messages in the batch must be acknowledged before the acknowledgement deadline expires. Even if one message in the batch is not acknowledged, the entire batch is re-queued for delivery which could result in messages being delivered more than once.
> Not only are the client libraries Batching messages, Pub/Sub also batches the messages internally to increase throughput and reduce costs.

If the lack of acking is relatively infrequent, you could just be running up against Pub/Sub's at-least-once delivery guarantees, where even messages for which you do send an ack could still be redelivered, even without the aforementioned caveat about batching.